# chaincode installation on peer0.org1 failed- ./byfn.sh -m up : Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger

I am getting an error after running script **./byfn.sh -m up**
Error: error getting endorser client chaincode: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051 failed to create new connection context deadline exceeded.

Comment: Did you solve that issue? Can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the peer container is still up. If the container has crashed, then it cannot be reached for endorsement.  Also checking the logs for peer0.org1.example.com will help.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to run **.byfn.sh -m down**  it will delete all old configuration of docker and container images,

now you can run **.byfn.sh -m up** , by using this command you can up your network in hyperledger.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to do `./byfn.sh` up and it will work. No need to use `-m flag` but first try to do `./byfn.sh` down so it cleans itself.

If you want a detailed study on byfn read this blog [here](https://www.devprovider.com/chaincode-on-byfn/)